# Save Blogger fetched data offline

Tags: java, android, json, gson, blogger

I am working on an app that fetch the data from Blogger using Google Blogger API. but the problem is every time user open the app it will fetch the data and show it. I want that the data must be stored on the first time the app is opened and have a option of refresh button, when clicked on that button it will refresh the data and again save it offline.

Here is the code for my getData method in main activity:

```
 private void getData(){
    Call<PostList> postList = BloggerAPI.getService().getPostList();
    postList.enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PostList> call, Response<PostList> response) {
            PostList list = response.body();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new PostAdapter(MainActivity.this, list.getItems()));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PostList> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

PS: I want to create a tutorial type app with this. Is it a good approach for creating tutorial apps. I find everywhere but did not find the exact solution, So thought to create it by blogger.

Comment: There are tons of android persistence libary you can explore like Room, greenDao, DBFlow, SugarORM, or a pure SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You can save data locally in SQLite and use a DAO to make things easier, or investigate SqlDelight and SqlBrite if you want some Rx solutions.  There are also storage solutions like Couchbase which are nosql.  Finally, you could store the data in shared preferences or even use the file system directly, although I wouldn't advocate for either of those in this case